# Separate byte in groups

Tags: c, byte, bit

So Im using this (its from another question I did),

```
unsigned char *y = resultado->informacion; 
int i = 0;
int tam = data->tamanho;
unsigned char resAfter; 
for (int i=0; i<tam;i++)
{
    unsigned char x = data->informacion[i];
    x <<= 3;
    if (i>0)
    {
        resAfter = (resAfter << 5) | x;
    }
    else
    {
        resAfter = x;
    }
}

printf("resAfter es  %s\n", resAfter);
```

so at the end I have this really long number (Im estimating about 43 bits), how can I get groups of 8 bits, I think im gettin something like (010101010101010.....000) and I want to separate this in groups of 8.

Another question, I know for sure that resAfter is going to have  n number of bits where n is a multiply of 8 plus 3, so my question is: is this possible? or c is going to complete the byte? like if I get 43 bits then c is going to fill them with 0 and complete so I have 48 bits; and is there a way to delete these 3 bits?

Im new on c and bitwise so sorry if what Im doing is reallly bad.

Comment: You are mixing strings and chars, `printf("resAfter es  %s\n", resAfter);` will result in undefined bahaviour (most likely a crash).

Comment: where am I doing this? sorry :*

Comment: What do you try to achieve ? A char (or unsigned char) is 8 bits long. So you throw 5 bits away at each `resAfter << 5`. All I can say if that a the end of the loop resAfter will be exactly 8 bits long what's probably not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in programming you deal with bytes (i think, at least in most cases), in C you deal with types of specific size (*depending on system you run it on*).
That said `char` **usually** has size of 1 byte, and I don't really think you can playing around with single bits. I mean u can do operation on them (`<<` for instance) in scale of single bits but i don't know of any standard way to preserve less than 8 bits in variable in C (though i may be wrong about it)

Comment: The type `char` is by definition the smallest type you can operate on. Thus, it is a “byte”. `char` has a size of at least 8 bits, exactly 8 bits on all but very obscure or special platforms.

Comment: @FUZxxl so there are no common platforms with `char`s in size of, say, 2 bytes ?

Comment: `byte` is defined as the lowest addressable unit of a platform. On your system, a byte may have 8 bit, but on a PDP-8, it has 12 bits. In this sense, a `char` is always one byte in size. If you're looking for a word for an 8-bit quantity, say “octet”.